# javascript: access object (array) by array notation string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, hierarchy

I would like to access the object provided only it's string path in form of array is known.

1.) there is an object, where

```
root["obj1"]["obj2"] = 1;
```

(in common case `root["obj1"]...["objN"]`)

2.) I have ONLY string objectPath known:

```
var objectPath = 'root["obj1"]["obj2"]'
```

3.) I need NOT only READ the object, but SET it's value, like

```
objectPath = 2;
//so root["obj1"]["obj2"] === 2
```

As I understand

1. there might be some options with eval(), but it gets the value, not the variable;
2. one can loop through all objects of root, make convertion to "root.obj1.obj2" (which is not the case, as "obj1" can easily be "obj with spaces1") and check if given string equals to current object in the loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/ACsPn/

Related Link: 
[Access object child properties using a dot notation string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975/access-object-child-properties-using-a-dot-notation-string)

Comment: yes, with eval(), i need to reset the object, change the 1 to 2 for example.

Comment: The accepted answer in the question you link to is much better than eval. It contains almost everything you need, you just have to use a different splitting and change it to a `set(path,value)` function.

Comment: one char "." against two chars "[" "]" is already some parser approach, I'm sure we can do better?

Comment: As it's not so easy to make such a function right after all, I wrote one. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function for you, trying to make it as pretty and reusable as possible :

```
function setProp(path, newValue, holder) {
    var t = path.split(/[\[\]"]+/).filter(function(v){return v}),
        l = t.pop(), s, o = holder || window;
    while (s = t.shift()) o = o[s];
    o[l] = newValue;
}
```

You use it like this :

```
setProp('root["obj1"]["obj2"]', 2);
```

If your root object isn't in a global variable, pass the relevant holder as third argument.

[Demonstration (open the console to see the changed root object)](http://jsbin.com/efupun/1/edit)

Comment: ok, thanks for ingenious split! Could not have done it on my own. Could you explain a bit what split and filter do. PS: var s; while (s = t.shift)...?

Comment: The filter is just here to ensure there is no empty value at one end of the array after split. [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) removes the first element from the array and returns it, and as `=` returns the assigned value, the loop ends when `shift` returns nothing (ie the array is empty).

Comment: (/[\[\]"]+/) < that was unclear, shift is ok, and by PS I meant your "s" variable is global, should not it be scoped to setProp function?

Comment: yes, I forgot the var on s. I'll add it. The `/[\[\]"]+/` part is a regular expression matching any not empty set of the chars `[`, `]` and `"`.

Comment: going to go read the book on regexp, again :) have a nice day!