# JS eval() function to interpret variables only

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm using eval to interpret some variables input.

Possible inputs are

```
"somevar"

"someobj.someprop['somekey'].someprop"

"window.someprop"
```

etc.

However I dont want it to *'execute'* any action. Like calling any function, changing any value of anything, declaring any variable.

So those should not be accepted (and any that change state of anything):

```
alert()
var somewar = 0
mywar = somewar
```

Is it possible via native js?

My target is just to interpret complex input variable "address" and return it.

Comment: There are many QA on this topic, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564027/javascript-access-object-array-by-array-notation-string

Comment: no it isn't. with es5 getters - it can run some logic. i would lock all these values into a single object. you might not want people to override `window.document`.

Comment: Be wary of eval() here is a good discussion: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/

Comment: I've just realized that any code that change state must contain '(' or '='

Comment: You could possibly use a parser generator, but it's probably overkill for what you are doing: http://pegjs.majda.cz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something like this, you may be better parsing the value.

```
var steps = input.match(/\['(?:[^']|\\.)+'\]|\["(?:[^"]|\\.)+"\]|[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/g);
var src = window;
var step;
while(step = steps.shift()) {
    if( step.charAt(0)) {
        // ['...'] or ["..."]
        step = step.substring(2,step.length-2);
    }
    src = src[step];
}
alert(src);
```

Since you're parsing out the string, there's no opportunity for malicious code to be executed.

Comment: I've made function of it. Didnt work for like interpret("jQuery")

Comment: Seems to work fine for me... Are you sure `window.jQuery` is defined when you call `interpret("jQuery")`?