# Accessing sub-object property with a plain string

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the following object:

```
var a = {
    x: {
        y: 'Good job!'
    }
    z: 'Nice try...'
}
```

and the following strings:

```
var key1 = "z";
var key2 = "x.y";
```

Is there a way to access the value of `y` by using the `key2` variable?

`console.log(a[key1])` will work because it will get evaled to `a['z']`, but `a[key2]` won't because it will get evaled to `a['x.y']` which is not valid.

Comment: try console.log(eval('a.' + key2));

Comment: Have a look at this question, it seems to be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975/access-object-child-properties-using-a-dot-notation-string?rq=1

Comment: @SohilDesai will this work only if the object is contained in ```window```? I'm guess yes, right?

Comment: No its not true but its not a good solution check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea