# Access JS object nested properties by string

Tags: javascript, json

I am reading JSON response into JS object. JSON source is like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "email": "info@test.com",
  "created_at": "2013-01-15 18:19:00.000000",
  "updated_at": "2016-04-27 09:13:40.000000",
  "user_profiles": {
    "data": {
      "first_name": "Mark",
      "last_name": "Webber",
      "birthday": "30.10.1979",
      "company": "Company d.o.o.",
      "phone": "",
      "mobile": "+386 123 123 123",
      "vatid": "1234567",
      "custom_fields": null,
      "deleted_at": null
    }
  }
}
```

I can access the properties like:

```
myObject.email
myObject.user_profiles.data.firstname
```

Is there a way to access nested properties via string? Something like

```
var property = "user_profiles.data.firstname"
myObject[property]
```

Comment: `myObject['user_profiles']['data']['first_name']` would produce the string `Mark`

Comment: Yes, on the surface, that's just the difference between dot notation `.` and bracket notation `[prop]`

Comment: myObject["user_profiles"]["data"]["first_name"]. If you need it generic, then you could split your input string and recursively check or something. But, if you know the structure ahead of time, then there's no need for that kind of interrogation.

Comment: I am having this dynamic component that renders data table from array of these objects. I would like to add the path to the nested property and get the vallue... What you are suggesting works yes but, need something like getColumnValue("user_profiles.data.firstname")

Comment: Felix beat me to it - here is another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975/access-object-child-properties-using-a-dot-notation-string

Comment: If you know the structure, then why not simply use myObject.user_profiles.data.first_name. That works fine. You're only going to need something like this, if your object model is unknown and you need dynamic access, but that's not likely.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the link, this looks like something I am after... Will try

Comment: This is perfect solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/33397682/255710

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
myObject['user_profiles']['data']['firstname']
```

Comment: I am having this dynamic component that renders data table from array of these objects. I would like to add the path to the nested property and get the value... What you are suggesting works yes but, need something like getColumnValue("user_profiles.data.firstname")

Comment: @PrimozRome The path is going to be the same for every element in the array, and you already know the path to the property in question, so why would you need it to be dynamic like this? If you don't know the property you want, then there's no point trying to get it, except in a loop. And if you do know it,then just use the dot (or object['property']) notation. See what I mean? It wouldn't be difficult to split a single fully qualified property and loop down to the required level to return the value though via a small function. I just don't see the need for that.

Comment: @ManoDestra: yes I know the path buy my table component is very dynamic. It goes thought the list of defined columns and I need to get the value for every column. So something like getColumnValue("email") on the first level, or getColumnValue("user_profiles.data.firstname") for the nested properties...

Comment: You can still achieve this for each property you need by using the normal object notation.