# Can't access dynamic nested JSON property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I’m creating a component to display a table based on JSON data, but nothing is shown for my column when the column's property key is `lieu.ville`. How do I fix this?

*Component:*

```
<template>
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
            <div class="row">
                <div v-for="col in colss" class="" :class="bootstrapClass">{{col | capitalize}}</div>
            </div>
        </li>

        <li v-for="(item,index ) in datas" class="list-group-item" :key="item['id']">
            <div class="row">
                <div v-for="(value,i) in columns" class="" :class="bootstrapClass">
                    <i>{{ item[value] }}</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</template>

<script>
var csrf_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

export default {
    props: ['colss','columns','datas','urlajax'],

    computed: {
        bootstrapClass: function() {
            return 'col-sm-' + (12 / this.colss.length );
        },
    },

    mounted: function () {
        console.log("testtttt");
    },

    filters: {
        capitalize: function (str) {
            return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

*Vue bootstrap:*

```
var listSessions = new Vue({
    el: '#listmodalSessions',
    data: {
        // collection des propriétés
        columns: ['id', 'ref_session', 'datesPeriodesConcat','lieu.ville'],
        // collection d'affichage
        colss: ['Id', 'Ref Session', 'Dates','Ville'],
        datas: [],
        urlPrefix:'/admin/User/' ,
    },
    methods: {
        showModal () {
            $('#sessionsModal').modal('show');
        },

        hideModal () {
            $('#sessionsModal').modal('hide');
        },
        // id Item représente l'id du user auquel appartiennent les permissions de la liste
        getDatas(idItem){

            var MonThis = this;
            MonThis.datas = [];

            $.ajax({
                url: this.urlajax,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    if (jqXHR.status === 200) {
                        MonThis.datas = data;
                        var index = 0;
                    }
                }
            });
        },

    },
    components: {modalTable},
});
```

*Sample data:*

```
[{
    "id": 6735,
    "formation_id": 8376,
    "statut_session_id": 1,
    "lieu_id": 1,
    "ref_session": "1 333 7020 19S 10 41 01",
    "prixSession": 1385,
    "intraInter": 1,
    "intraInSitu": 0,
    "commentaires": null,
    "created_at": "2019-03-25 17:31:29",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-25 17:31:29",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "periodes": [{
        "id": 5634,
        "session_id": 6735,
        "salle_id": 43,
        "date_debut": "2019-10-07",
        "date_fin": "2019-10-11",
        "commentaires": null,
        "created_at": "2019-03-25 17:31:29",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-25 17:31:29",
        "deleted_at": null
    }],
    "lieu": {
        "id": 1,
        "ville": "Paris",
        "cp": "75",
        "region": null,
        "displaySite": 1,
        "created_at": "2019-03-13 13:24:36",
        "updated_at": "2019-03-13 13:24:36"
    },
    "datesPeriodesConcat": "2019-10-07 au 2019-10-11",
    "lieu2Display": "Paris",
    "link": "<a class=\"btn btn-info\" href=\"\/session\/6735\">Session<\/a>"
}]
```

Comment: Can you add `datas` array in the question? That would help

Comment: Thanks I've added the Json data.

Comment: You are not assigning `datas`... And who call `getDatas`?

Comment: All datas are displayed except lieu.ville in the v-for

Comment: How could I pass my 'lieu.ville' as bracket notation dynamically instead ?

Comment: getDatas is called on click event not listed here because it's useless to resolve the problem

Comment: ah ok, I see MonThis referecing `this`.

Comment: This should have been a very simple problem. I tried around in codesandbox, but nothing totally dynamic stood out.
What is your constraint that you must use 'bracket notation dynamically instead' rather than using some logic to control this display?

Comment: Ok. This has nothing to do with JSON or Vue. Basically you are trying to access item["lieu.ville"] which is not valid syntax to access child properties of JS Object.

Comment: Dot notation doesn't work too. I don't want to create a component for each view

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33397682/986862

Comment: you probably need to flatten your object and then use your display code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Comment: {{item.lieu.ville}} works but not dynamically with {{item[value] }} or{{ item.value }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem...

`item['lieu.ville']` is not the same as `item.lieu.ville`. The former looks up a property named `lieu.ville` in `item`, which doesn't exist in this case. The latter looks up `lieu` in `item`, then `ville` in the result.

One way to solve this is to programmatically split the given object key by `.` so that the correct property can be resolved:

```
methods: {
  getValue(item, key) {
    return key.split('.').reduce((obj,k) => obj[k] || {}, item)

    /** The one-liner above is equivalent to the following **/

    const keys = key.split('.')
    for (const k of keys) {
      if (!item) break
      item = item[k]
    }
    return item || {}
  }
},
```

#### *Suboptimal* usage...

You could use that `getValue` method in your template like this:

```
<li v-for="item in datas">
  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="key in columns">
      <i>{{ getValue(item, key) }}</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

[image: Edit Resolving prop by method in Vue template]

But using such methods in the template is [inefficient](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods) because the method is called on every render, producing the same result each time.

#### Something better...

You could use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) instead, which gets cached to avoid unnecessary recalculations on render. The computed prop (e.g., named `tableData`) would contain new table data that has its column's items already resolved:

```
computed: {
  tableData() {
    return this.datas.map(item => ({
      ...item,
      columns: this.columns.map(key => this.getValue(item, key))
    }))
  }
}
```

Then, you could use the `tableData` prop in your template like this:

```
<li v-for="item in tableData">
  <div class="row">
    <div v-for="value in item.columns">
      <i>{{ value }}</i>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

[image: Edit Resolving table data in computed prop in Vue template]

Comment: Thank you, it's a bit tricky but it works ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: @Brian85 No problem :)