# generic function for sorting array

Tags: typescript

I wrote generic function for sorting array in typescript

```
export function sortArray(incomingArray: any[], sortField: string = '', sortOrder: string = 'asc'): any[] {
  if (!sortField) {
    return incomingArray;
  }

  let result: any[] = [];
  result = incomingArray.sort((a, b) => {
    let testData = a.ohlc['priceInUsd'];

    if (a[sortField] < b[sortField]) {
      return sortOrder === 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
    }

    if (a[sortField] > b[sortField]) {
      return sortOrder === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
    }

    return 0;
  });
  return result;
}
```

Wokring perfectly fine till structure is inside one array. Problem is if I have more complex data like in photo and then "`a[sortField]`" doesn't wok well any more

[image]

How to chnage "`a[sortField]`" that will be more generic if I have more complex data and not need to write "`a.x[sortField]`"

Comment: This is not about sorting: you know about sorting. The question is how to access an attribute in a deep structure using a string path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access object child properties using a dot notation string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975/access-object-child-properties-using-a-dot-notation-string)