# Convert comma seperated values into object specified method

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript

Hi I am trying to achieve following behaviors with javascript

```
let fieldsArray = ['clientMap', 0, 'legalEntityNumber']
```

somehow I want to get convert above data into following way

```
['clientMap'][0]['legalEntityNumber']
```

I tried with  `fieldsArray.join('[]')` but its not working as expected. please help. Thanks

Comment: What is `['clientMap'][0]['legalEntityNumber']`? This evaluates to `'clientMap'.legalEntityNumber`, which in turn is `undefined`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975/access-object-child-properties-using-a-dot-notation-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im understanding you correctly (and you want a string i.e. `"[clientMap][0][legalEntityNumber]"`) this would be how to do that...

```
let fieldsArrayString = ['clientMap', 0, 'legalEntityNumber'].map(item=>`[${item}]`).join('');
```

or

```
let fieldsArrayString = ['clientMap', 0, 'legalEntityNumber'].reduce((acc, cur) => `${acc}[${cur}]`, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do assuming you intended to convert the items to array of arrays (Type: (string|number)[][])

```
let fieldsArrayArray = ['clientMap', 0, 'legalEntityNumber'].map(item=>[item])
```

Basically mapping each element of the array outputting single item array.

If the output should be string then for some reason (Type: string)

```
let fieldsArrayStringArrays = ['clientMap', 0, 'legalEntityNumber'].map(item=>`[${item}]`).join("")
```

Comment: thanks Itay! it works, however I achieve the result using  _.set function of lodash library _.set(dataCopy, ['clientMap', 0, 'legalEntityNumber'], value);