# Convert a string chain of property accessor to give the actual value (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, object, properties

My question is quiet simple.

I have an object that looks like that:

```
const person = {
   name: 'David',
   locations: [
      {
         country: 'Belgium',
      },
      {
         country: 'France',
      },
      {
         country: 'Ireland',
      },
   ],
};
```

For example I have "person.locations[0].country" as string, that mix dot-notation and bracket notation.

is there a way to convert to an actual chain of property accessor that returns a value?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your goal to access an object from that dot-notation string? If so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8052100/519413

Comment: *is there a way*, YES. How to, for this, we will need more info. Is it object or Set/ Map or array?

Comment: I missed some details, I changed a little bit the description.