# How to set sub-level property from string for javascript objects

Tags: javascript, object, key

I have a player object with sub property type:

```
'player': {
            'count': 11,
            'type': 'forward'
}
```

Now i would like to call `setPlayer( {...playerDetails, [key]: e.target.value})` to keep the existing player object and only change one property (i.e. `player.type`).

Using `[key]: e.target.value` works fine with changing root level property like `player` , but how can i use key to set the sub level property `player.type`.

`['player.type']: e.target.value` will only create a 'player.type' string property in root level but not override nor create sub-level property 'type' in player.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that will parse that. You need to split it into an array and then loop over the elements.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051975/access-object-child-properties-using-a-dot-notation-string for how to do that.

Comment: ok, so i have to build a work-around. thank you!

Comment: It depends on whether this needs to be dynamic. See the answer below for how to do it with fixed properties.

Comment: i have dynamic input (key can be any object property on any level)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking for is:

```js
const [key1, key2] = "player.type".split('.')
const playerDetails = {foo: 'bar'}, e = {target: {value: 12}}
const res = {...playerDetails, [key1]: {...playerDetails[key1] ?? {}, [key2]: e.target.value} }
console.log(res)
```

This approach is not feasible for more than two levels,  though it works in a recursive algorithm too:

```js
const data = {foo: 'bar', player: {name: 'baz'}}
const prop = "player.value.default"
const setProp = (obj, [prop, ...path], value) => !prop ? value : {...obj, [prop]: setProp(obj[prop] ?? {}, path, value)}
console.log(setProp(data, prop.split('.'), 42))
```

But there are more efficient ways to do it.

Comment: what is key2 doing? i am passing key='player.type' and want it to create player: {type: someValue }

Comment: @instantlink In your example it says `player.type`, which I understood as `player` being key1 and `type` being key2.

Comment: @instantlink I think it is clearer now. This stuck with me a bit lol. Good question!

Comment: i had same idea of splitting the key but was asking if there was any trick to do it easier since it seems to be a quite common task to do

Comment: @instantlink Oh, it reads like you asked "how to use key to set the sub level property", i.e. how to use destructuring on a deeper level than just the first.

Comment: your sample works fine for up to level 2. Thanks for pointing out to the recursive solution! Yet i was looking for a more generic approach in this topic (need it up to level 3). Seems ['player.type'] will always result in "player.type" and not "player: { type: ...."

Comment: @instantlink Not sure what you mean, the two level statement gives you `"player: { type: ....` and the function resolves it for any level. Made the first one a snipped to be sure and it works as expected. Anyway, that was fun, cheers